# Difference between passing arrays to functions as func(int * arr[][]) and func(int arr[][])?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I did some search about this at google and I found out that they don't have any difference but I have the following code with two functions adding rows of a matrix, one for each type, and they give me different answers.

Also, I get a warning in GNU GCC compiler (windows 10) that say:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'addRow' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define R 2
#define C 2

void addRow(int arr[R][C]);
void addRow2(int * arr[R][C]);
void printArr(int arr[R][C]);

int main()
{
    int arr[R][C];
    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < C; k++) {
            printf("Enter %d-th row %d-th element:", i+1, k+1);
            scanf(" %d", &arr[i][k]);
        }
    }
    printArr(arr);
    addRow(arr); // prints 11 and 6
    addRow2(arr); // prints 26 and 12

    return 0;
} /* =============== Main ================= */

/* Function that takes "int arr[][]" */
void addRow(int arr[R][C]) {

    for(int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for(int l = 0; l < C; l++) {
            rowSum += arr[j][l];
        }
        printf("Sum of %d-th row = %d\n", j+1, rowSum);
    }
}

/* Function that takes "int * arr[][]" */
void addRow2(int * arr[R][C]) {

    for(int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for(int l = 0; l < C; l++) {
            rowSum += arr[j][l];
        }
        printf("Sum of %d-th row = %d\n", j+1, rowSum);
    }
}
```

When we enter 5 and 6 for first row and 2 and 4 for the second row:
**Result from function taking "int arr[][]" is:**
for the first row: 11
for second row: 6
**Result from function taking "int * arr[][]" is:**
for first row: 26
for second row: 12

Can you please help me understand the difference and how to remove that warning?

Comment: `int arr[][]` is a 2D array of `int`. `int * arr[][]` is a 2D array of pointers. They are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

`int arr[R][C]` is a 2D array of `int`.
`int * arr[R][C]` is a 2D array of `int*` pointers, which doesn't make any sense given how that function is implemented.

Unfortunately gcc isn't doing you any favour in default mode where it doesn't give errors from C language violations, just warnings. Because `addRow2(arr);` isn't valid C and what happens if a compiler in non-C mode spits out a binary regardless, is anyone's guess.

Probably your strange output from `addRow2` can be explained about it giving you 64 bit chunks somehow, but there is nothing interesting to learn from studying it, since it is an ill-formed program.

Compile with `-pedantic-errors` if you want to block invalid C from compiling.